# R: Number of classes is not equal to 2

Tags: r

I am getting the following error when trying to generate a lift chart for a random forest model being run through rattle:

```
Error in prediction(crs$pr, no.miss) : 
  Number of classes is not equal to 2.
ROCR currently supports only evaluation of binary classification tasks.
```

My code is as follows:
# Evaluate model performance.

```
# Lift Chart: requires the ROCR package.

library(ROCR)

# Obtain predictions for the rf model on TBA_jul21c.csv [**train**].

crs$pr <- predict(crs$rf, newdata=na.omit(crs$dataset[crs$sample,    c(crs$input, crs$target)]), type="prob")[,2]

# Remove observations with missing target.

no.miss   <- na.omit(na.omit(crs$dataset[crs$sample, c(crs$input,   crs$target)])$targetvar)
miss.list <- attr(no.miss, "na.action")
attributes(no.miss) <- NULL

if (length(miss.list))
{
 pred <- prediction(crs$pr[-miss.list], no.miss)
} else
{
  pred <- prediction(crs$pr, no.miss)
}

# Convert rate of positive predictions to percentage.

per <- performance(pred, "lift", "rpp")
per@x.values[[1]] <- per@x.values[[1]]*100

# Plot the lift chart.
plot(per, col="#CC0000FF", lty=1, xlab="Caseload (%)", add=FALSE)
```

My dataset has 127 variables, including a target variable with Y/N labels. I am reading the dataset in as follows:

```
crs$dataset <- read.csv("file:///C:/MastersC/TBA_jul21c.csv",    na.strings=c(".", "NA", "", "?"), strip.white=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")

#============================================================
# Rattle timestamp: 2015-07-22 08:36:53 x86_64-w64-mingw32 

# Note the user selections. 

# Build the training/validate/test datasets.

set.seed(crv$seed) 
crs$nobs <- nrow(crs$dataset) # 72824 observations 
crs$sample <- crs$train <- sample(nrow(crs$dataset), 0.7*crs$nobs) # 50976   observations
crs$validate <- sample(setdiff(seq_len(nrow(crs$dataset)), crs$train),   0.15*crs$nobs) # 10923 observations
crs$test <- setdiff(setdiff(seq_len(nrow(crs$dataset)), crs$train),     crs$validate) # 10925 observations
```

I think it has something to do with the target variable, but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been stuck on this for a number of hours. By the way, this is my first StackOverflow post, so feel free to chastise me if I am not posting correctly. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you distill your question into a reproducible example?

Comment: Your assumption should be correct: how many distinct values are their in your target variable?  I assume that there are actually  more than 2 (maybe a text for "missing" or something else?

Comment: Yes there are only two distinct values "Y" and "N" - which makes the error message hard to comprehend

Comment: Roman, what are you looking for that would help distill the question?

Comment: Just to add when I run an error (confusion) matrix  I get a matrix of zeros, even though the standard confusion matrix output generated by the random forest produces sensible output.

Comment: Update: I have just figured it out. There were so many missing values in my dataset that they pretty much wiped all the records for evaluation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Predobject is to be created with 2 inputs to the prediction function:

1. The list (vector) of predictions (model output, odds or
   probabilities for each member),
2. The list (vector) of labels: 0 or 1

as shown in following:

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
```

In the case of the question, it is very likely that 2nd parameter (no.miss in above question) is not list of binary info (0,1).

If you get this error, please check your 2nd parameter. I had the same error and providing correct info solved it.